# Clear countdown timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I have this function that implements a countdown (MM:SS). I pass the minutes and seconds in the function and the countdown will start. Now, I'd like the countdown to reset and restart everytime I pass new values in. Currently what happens is that if I call the countdown function multiple times then I will have multiple timers running together while instead I need to reset and restart the same timer everytime I pass in new minutes and seconds. Thanks

```
function countdown(minutes, seconds)
    {
        var endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

        function twoDigits( n )
        {
            return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
        }

        function updateTimer()
        {
            canvas.style.color = "black";
            canvas.innerHTML = "00:00"; //clear canvas
            msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
            if ( msLeft < 1000 )                
                flashyText();
            else {
                canvas.style.color = "white";
                time = new Date( msLeft );
                hours = time.getUTCHours();
                mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
                canvas.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds());
                setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
            }
        }

        endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
        updateTimer();
    }
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the id of the current timer and cancel it before setting the new one.

Courtesy w3schools: -

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello") }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);

}
```